# document.querySelector retorna Undefined

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso recuperar um valor de um input da minha tela de login e passar para a minha tela de home.

Fiz um `document.querySelector` para acessar o meu input através do `ID` e armazenei esse valor em uma const chamanda `empresa`.

Dentro do meu home eu importei essa constante e fiz um console.log para verificar se eu estava recebendo os dados, ao mesmo tempo em que inseria ela dentro do meu setState para eu pegar a posição do Array igual ao número da empresa. Porém o valor retorna **Undefined**.

Também recebo um Warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Como posso resolver isso?

Tela de Login:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    
    import {LoginService} from "../../services/LoginService"
    
    import './loginPage.css'
    
    //Recebe o número da empresa
    export const empresa =  parseInt(document.querySelector("#empresa").value)
    
    
    class Login extends Component   {
   
        
        
        fazerLogin  =   infosDoEvento   =>  {
            
            
    
            infosDoEvento.preventDefault();
              const dadosDeLogin    =   {
                    login:  this.refs.inputLogin.value,
                    senha:  this.refs.inputSenha.value,
    
            };
            console.log(dadosDeLogin)
            LoginService.logar(dadosDeLogin)
            .then(()    =>  {
                    this.props.history.push("/home");
            })
            .catch(err  =>  {
                    console.error(`[Erro    ${err.status}]`,    err.message);
            });
        }
    
        
        
       
        render() {
            return (
                
                    <div className="loginPage">
                        <div className="container">
                       
                                <h2 className="loginPage__title">Seja bem vindo!</h2>
                                <form className="loginPage__form" action="/" onSubmit={this.fazerLogin}>
                                    <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                        <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Login</label> 
                                        <input ref="inputLogin" className="loginPage__input" type="text" id="login" name="senha"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                        <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="senha">Senha</label> 
                                        <input ref="inputSenha" className="loginPage__input" type="password" id="senha" name="senha"/>
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div>
                                        <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Empresa</label> 
                                        <input ref="inputEmpresa" className="loginPage__input" type="text"  id="empresa" name="empresa" />
    
                                    </div>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
    
    
                                        <button className="loginPage__btnLogin" type="submit">
                                            Logar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                       
                        </div>
                    </div>
             
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Login;
```

Tela de Home:

```
 

    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Container, Table} from 'react-bootstrap'
    import Extrato from '../Extrato'
    import NavBar from '../NavBar'
    
    import {consultarResumo} from '../../services/Home/index'
    
    //Importa o valor da Empresa
    import {empresa} from '../Login/index'
    
    //Imprime o valor da Empresa
    window.onload = teste => {console.log(empresa)}
    
    
    class Home  extends Component   {
        
        
    
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
    
            this.state = {
               
                empresaId: 0,
                    nomeEmpresa: "EMPRESA UM S/A",
                    cnpj: 0,
                
                dadosBancario: {
                    banco: 0,
                    bancoNome: "CONTA SIMPLES",
                    agencia: 0,
                    conta: 0,
                    digitoConta: 0
        },
                    saldo: 0
                
            }
            
        }
    
        componentDidMount(){
            
            //Consulta na API e busca a posição igual o valor da empresa
            consultarResumo().then(dados => this.setState(dados[empresa]))
            
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
            <Container>
            <NavBar></NavBar>   
               <br/>
                <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>{this.state.nomeEmpresa}</th>
                            <th>CNPJ: {this.state.cnpj}</th>
                            <th>Número do Banco: {this.state.dadosBancario.banco}</th>
                            <th>{this.state.dadosBancario.bancoNome}</th>
                            <th>Agência: {this.state.dadosBancario.agencia}</th>
                            <th>Conta: {this.state.dadosBancario.conta}</th>
                            <th>Digito da Conta: {this.state.dadosBancario.digitoConta}</th>
                            <th>Saldo: {this.state.saldo.toLocaleString("PT-BR", {style: "currency", currency : "BRL"})}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </Table>
                    <Extrato></Extrato>
            </Container>
            )
        }
        
    }
    
    export default Home;
```

Comment: ta certo isso aqui `parseInt(document.querySelector("#empresa")).value`? nao seria `parseInt(document.querySelector("#empresa").value)`?

Comment: Mesmo mudando a posição, o problema persiste.

Comment: Sim, foi so um detalhe que chamei atencao pra resolver. Agora mude `onSubmit={this.fazerLogin}` para `onSubmit={(event) => this.fazerLogin(event)}` e veja se o *warning* ainda aparece

Comment: O Warning continua, mas agora temos um outro erro: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at Module../src/View/Login/index.js e a variavel aparece como undefined no console na tela de home.

Comment: OK, vou escrever minha resposta com os testes que eu fiz aqui e vamos ver se resolve seu problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo os testes aqui, acho que posso resolver seu problema. Vamos por parte...

- Primeiro, os `inputs` no React tem um comportamento diferente do tradicional, como a [**documentação do React**](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) explica:

> Em HTML, elementos de formulário como ,  e  normalmente mantêm seu próprio estado e o atualiza baseado na entrada do usuário. Em React, o estado mutável é normalmente mantido na propriedade state dos componentes e atualizado apenas com setState().

- Logo, vamos refazer o seu codigo do componente `Login`, e vamos criar um `state` para manter os estados do `inputs` que serão alterados conforme o usuário interage. Lembrando que o `this.refs` [está depreciado](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs), então não vamos usá-lo. Espero que não tenha problema. Vou comentar o código com explicações. Vamos acrescentar metodos para tratar os `inputs`

```js
 // vamos adicionar um estado para manter os dados dos inputs.
  state = {
    login: '',
    senha: '',
    empresa: ''
  };

  // agora vamos adicionar metodos para tratar toda vez que um input mudar
  // depois vamos adicionar atributo `onChange` para cada input o metodo
  // equivalente
  inputLoginChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ login: event.target.value });
  };
  inputSenhaChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ senha: event.target.value });
  };
  inputEmpresaChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ empresa: event.target.value });
  };

  fazerLogin = infosDoEvento => {
    infosDoEvento.preventDefault();
    const dadosDeLogin = {
      login: this.state.login,
      senha: this.state.senha,
      empresa: this.state.empresa
    };
    console.log(dadosDeLogin);
    // ...
  };
```

No formulário, nos `inputs` vamos adicionar atributos `value` e `onChange`:

```js
render() {
    return (

      <div className="loginPage">
        <div className="container">

          <h2 className="loginPage__title">Seja bem vindo!</h2>
          <form className="loginPage__form" action="/" onSubmit={this.fazerLogin}>
            <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
              <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Login</label>
              <input ref="inputLogin" className="loginPage__input" type="text" id="login" name="senha" value={this.state.login} onChange={(event) => this.inputLoginChangeHandler(event)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
              <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="senha">Senha</label>
              <input ref="inputSenha" className="loginPage__input" type="password" id="senha" name="senha" value={this.state.senha} onChange={(event) => this.inputSenhaChangeHandler(event)}/>
            </div>

            <div>
              <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Empresa</label>
              <input ref="inputEmpresa" className="loginPage__input" type="text" id="empresa" name="empresa" value={this.state.empresa} onChange={(event) => this.inputEmpresaChangeHandler(event)}/>

            </div>
            <br></br>
            <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">


              <button className="loginPage__btnLogin" type="submit">
                Logar
                                    </button>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>

    );
```

- Nos teste que fiz, isso foi o bastante para resolver o *warning*. Tente fazer os testes. Lembrando que não coloquei todo o seu código, mas creio que voçe pode adaptar.
- Agora, vamos resolver o problema do `empresa` ser `undefined`. Acontece o seguinte, quando tentamos capturar `parseInt(document.querySelector("#empresa").value)` antes do React renderizar o componente Login, o componente HTML input com o *id empresa* não existe ainda, logo não tem como termos o valor deste input, sempre sera `null`.
- Se voce precisa valor de `empresa` em outra pagina, ***NÃO USE EXPORTS***. Sugiro que use um gerenciador de estado como [Redux](https://medium.com/@hliojnior_34681/entenda-react-e-redux-de-uma-vez-por-todas-c761bc3194ca), transferir valores de componente filho para componente pai([veja aqui](https://medium.com/@joaolucasluc/comunicacao-entre-componentes-react-8574108b5043)),ou até mesmo usar o `localStorage`([veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)), onde voçe pode armazenar o valor de *empresa* e usar em outra pagina. Por exemplo, na função `fazerLogin`, salve o valor de *empresa* no `localStorage`:

```js
 fazerLogin = infosDoEvento => {
    infosDoEvento.preventDefault();

    const dadosDeLogin = {
      login: this.state.login,
      senha: this.state.senha,
      empresa: this.state.empresa
    };
    
    window.localStorage.setItem('empresa', dadosDeLogin.empresa);
    // ...
  };
```

E onde voce precisar do valor de `empresa` use por exemplo:

```js
let empresa = window.localStorage.getItem('empresa');
```

Espero que minha resposta possa ter te ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Sua ajuda foi incrível! Além de resolver o problema me deu uma aula e me ajudou a entender muitas coisas e a melhorar minha forma de programar.